# How to Preprocess csv data for association analysis using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining, apriori

I am working on a task to preprocess csv file with python. Task is to read original.csv file containing items bought in one transaction per row. I need to create another csv file which should look similar to target.csv file which will display all data in one transaction per row.

original.csv (Here for any single transaction items purchased is listed per row)

[image: original.csv file contents]

sample data which looks like contents of original.csv file

```
 Transaction Id  Items
  1               Eggs
  1               Yogurt
  1               Apple
  2               Tea
  2               Rice
```

In target.csv all data under one transaction is listed under one row .So row 1 contains all items purchased in transaction number 1.

[image: target.csv file contents]

sample data which looks like contents of target.csv file

```
1 Eggs,Yogurt,Apple
2 Tea Rice
```

I am using below python code to transform original.csv to target.csv

```
#reading csv file
newdf = pd.read_csv('original.csv',header=None)

#creating an empty list
basket = []

'''
this code will enumerate through all transaction number in original csv file 
and create a list with items belonging to one transaction. After for loop 
execution gets completed list 'basket' will contain list of list containing 
items of all transactions
'''

for id in newdf[1].unique():
    a = [newdf[2][i] for i, j in enumerate(newdf[1]) if j == id]
    basket.append(a)

'''
Now a new csv file is created with all items of one transaction in one 
row getting written in this file.
'''
with open('target.csv','w',newline='') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    writer.writerows(basket)
writeFile.close()
```

Transaction number 17 from output csv file

[image: Transaction number 17 in output csv file]

```
17    milk  hand soap   pasta   individual meals    spaghetti sauce cereals sandwich loaves hand soap
```

Transaction number 17 in original csv file

[image: X]

```
 Transaction Id  Items
  17               Yogurt
  17               Milk
  17               hand soap
  17               pasta
  17               individual meals 
  ...
```

For transaction number 17 one item 'Yogurt' is missing in the target.csv file. I also checked for some other transaction numbers and found items missing.

How to display all data of one transaction in one row in new csv file?

Comment: Instead of linking to imgur for images of the .csv files, formatting a sample of them like code tends to be more useful. It'll probably increase the folks who will seriously look at your question.

Comment: Can you create a data set instead of links to data screenshots? E.g. data = 'col1,col2,col3\n1,2,3\n4,5,6' as sample? Since pd.read_csv(io.String(data) will mimic your input.

Comment: Have added the sample file contents.Thank you